# How to parser a file which include other file?

Tags: boost-spirit

I want to parser a type os file which has main file and included files with spirit. A little like C++ file which has some include files, and the include files can include other files. I havn't found the relevent answer from the examples of spirit QI.  Could someone tell me how to realize it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement include directives using boost::spirit::lex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525216/how-do-i-implement-include-directives-using-boostspiritlex)

Answer (score 0):

Boost spirit has no built-in mechanism for locating or opening files.

You will need to use boost to parse your include syntax, and then use code outside of the parser to open the identified files recursively.

Alternatively, if you really need to handle the #include in-place, you could define a [semantic action function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html) which executes another parse on the targeted file.